# Dynamically Re-Sizing Images in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, listview

I'm currently having trouble resizing images in a ListView that uses a DataTemplate to put Images into a WrapPanel then into the ListView.
This is an image of the program:

[image: Program]

I currently use this as my Data Template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <WrapPanel>
            <Image
                Width="300"
                Height="300" 
                Stretch="Fill" 
                Source="{Binding}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I then use this data template in my ListView:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
              Name="MovieListView"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movie_posters_list}"
              Background="Black"
              SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid  Columns="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
```

And this is the code behind for populating the ListView Source:

```
public void LoadImages()
    {
        List<String> filenames = new List<String>(System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(movie_poster_path, "*.jpg"));

        foreach (String filename in filenames)
        {
            this.movie_posters_list.Add(new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename)));
            Console.WriteLine("filename " + filename);
            Match regex_match = Regex.Match(filename.Trim(), regex_pattern);
        }
        MovieListView.ItemsSource = movie_posters_list;
    }
```

So currently, I can edit the data template in the XAML and change the image width and height and it will reflect when I load the program.
I can also change the amount of columns in the UniformGrid and it will reflect when I load the program.
Is there any way that I can change these values dynamically in code behind so that I can slide a slider to change the size of the  and the amount of columns in the UniformGrid?

**Question Supplemented:**
Here I have 3 columns, There is black space on both sides because there is not enough space for a fourth column to display.
[image: 3ColumnsWithBlackSpace]
I want to try to adjust the logic so that when I have 3 columns it will adjust the image size up so that the 3 columns will fill the available space horizontally. This window will never resize as I have it in fullscreen.

Here is an example with how I would like to have it display with 4 columns.
[image: 4ColumnsPerfect]

If I drag the slider down a bit it will display 4 columns like this, which I don't want.
[image: 4 columns Imperfect]

So basically I would like all of the images to fill the max space on the screen at all times, I would like the slider to snap when there is enough space to fit the next column of images.

Example of it functioning, When slider is all the way to the right (at the max image size) it will perfectly fit 4 columns as I drag the slider to the left it will snap to the position that perfectly fits 5 columns in the view and so on.
Is this possible?

Visual of what I would like to be displayed:

Minimum amount of columns: 4

Maximum amount of columns: 11

When I move the slider, I would like it to only allow the images to be displayed like the following images:

**4 Columns:**
[image: 4 Columns]

**5 Columns:**
[image: 5 Columns]

**6 Columns:**
[image: 6 Columns]

**7 Columns:**
[image: 7 Columns]

**8 Columns:**
[image: 8 Columns]

**9 Columns:**
[image: 9 Columns]

**10 Columns:**
[image: 10 Columns]

**11 Columns:**
[image: 11 Columns]

Comment: EDIT: Is there any way that I can change these values dynamically in code behind so that I can slide a slider to change the size of the Images and the amount of columns in the UniformGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to create a converter.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Converters
{
    public class WidthToColumnsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values?.Length == 2 && (values[0] is double widthImage) && (values[1] is double widthPanel))
                return (int)Math.Floor(widthPanel / widthImage);
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        public static WidthToColumnsConverter Instance { get; } = new WidthToColumnsConverter();


    }
    public class WidthToColumnsConverterExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return WidthToColumnsConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
    <Grid>
        <FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                <Image Width="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"
                       Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                       Stretch="Fill"
                       Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="slider"
                Minimum="50"  Maximum="500" SmallChange="5" TickFrequency="5"
                Value="300"/>
        <ListView x:Name="MovieListView"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}"
                  Background="Black"
                  SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movie_posters_list}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <UniformGrid.Columns>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:WidthToColumnsConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="slider"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="MovieListView"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </UniformGrid.Columns>
                    </UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

**P.S.** There are small nuances with determining the exact panel size for elements.
In the example I have shown, in some cases, elements in width may take a slightly larger size and a horizontal ScrollBar will be displayed.
This is due to the fact that the example takes the Parent ListBox as the basis for calculations.
But it, besides elements, also contains Border and Vertical ScrollBar.

You can remove the influence of Border with this binding:

```xml
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <UniformGrid.Columns>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:WidthToColumnsConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="slider"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                         AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </UniformGrid.Columns>
    </UniformGrid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

But this still gives the size without taking into account the space occupied by the Vertical ScrollBar.
I did not find a simple way to get the place allocated for the elements by binding.
You can subtract some constant from the width to take into account the size of the Vertical ScrollBar.

```cs
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values?.Length == 2 && (values[0] is double widthImage) && (values[1] is double widthPanel))
                return (int)Math.Floor((widthPanel - 30) / widthImage);
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
```

**P.S.S.** Converter with the transfer through a parameter of the value by which the width of the panel must be reduced.

```cs
    public class WidthToColumnsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public static readonly DoubleConverter DoubleConverter = (DoubleConverter)TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(double));
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            double param = 0;
            if (DoubleConverter.IsValid(parameter))
                param = (double)DoubleConverter.ConvertFrom(parameter);
            if (values?.Length == 2 && (values[0] is double widthImage) && (values[1] is double widthPanel))
                return (int)Math.Floor((widthPanel - param) / widthImage);
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
```

Examle:

```xml
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <UniformGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <UniformGrid.Columns>
            <!--The parameter value can be changed during the execution (Debug) of the project.
                This makes the process of selecting it for a specific layout very convenient.-->
            <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:WidthToColumnsConverter}"
                          ConverterParameter="35">
                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="slider"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                            RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </UniformGrid.Columns>
    </UniformGrid>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

**SUPPLEMENT:**

> Example of it functioning, When slider is all the way to the right (at the max image size) it will perfectly fit 4 columns as I drag the slider to the left it will snap to the position that perfectly fits 5 columns in the view and so on. Is this possible?

If I understand you correctly, then you need to resize the images so that they add up to always fill the entire width of the panel.
If so, this is the default behavior for the UniformGrid.
You just need to remove the explicit dimensions from the elements and bind the width of the panel to the space provided for it.

Example:

```xml
    <Grid>
        <FrameworkElement.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
                <Image Stretch="Fill"
                       Source="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
            <RelativeSource x:Key="ancestorScroll"
                            Mode="FindAncestor"
                            AncestorType="{x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}"/>
        </FrameworkElement.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Slider x:Name="slider"
                Minimum="50"  Maximum="500" SmallChange="5" TickFrequency="5"
                Value="300"/>
        <ListView x:Name="MovieListView"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="3"
                  ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ItemTemplate}"
                  Background="Black"
                  SelectionChanged="MovieListView_SelectionChanged"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path = movie_posters_list}">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <!--Explicit setting of the Panel width from the size of the parent container.
                    If necessary, you can add a converter that corrects this value.-->
                    <UniformGrid  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                  Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
                                        RelativeSource={StaticResource ancestorScroll}}">
                        <UniformGrid.Columns>

                            <!--The parameter value can be changed during the execution (Debug) of the project.
                            This makes the process of selecting it for a specific layout very convenient.-->
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:WidthToColumnsConverter}"
                                          ConverterParameter="35">
                                <Binding Path="Value" ElementName="slider"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                                         RelativeSource="{StaticResource ancestorScroll}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </UniformGrid.Columns>
                    </UniformGrid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This looks very straight forward, I will give this a go when I get home tonight! If it works you are a life saver!

Comment: I supplemented my answer with some nuances of applying the code from it. Read this supplement.

Comment: I just applied the code and it works great!!! I am still getting the horizontal scrollbar pop up when the slider is set to certain values. I am going to work with this code and see if I can get it to display a bit cleaner, this has helped me so much! Thank you! I will let you know what I come up with!

Comment: Subtract the constant from the width.
I showed in the code from the supplement in my answer how to do this.
The example uses the constant 30 - that's enough for me.
Perhaps you need to increase it to 35 ... 40.
You can also pass it through the converter parameter so as not to change the converter code for each value.

Comment: I added the code for such a converter to my answer.

Comment: Okay so the adjustments I've made so far is setting the minimum size to 150 and the max to 450 on the slider. Those are the largest and smallest I want the images to display.
Sorry for asking for the spoon fed version of this XD. I only have some C# knowledge and I am new to WPF and XAML, I have always used WinForms so Binding are completely foreign to me.
So at all ticks on the slider I am no longer getting a horizontal scrollbar by using a constant of 90.

Comment: I have realized that this may be too dynamic for me as it allows for so many width values to be set, which in turn will leave black space on either side of the column before allowing enough space for another picture to be displayed in the column.
How would I go about the following logic: If there is 7 columns, set the width and height to X. If there is 6 columns set the width and height to X. This way I can figure out the width and height needed for a specific amount of columns to completely fill the space? I realize this method would be very specific to my case and not the best overall way.

Comment: I didn't quite understand you.
What width do you need to set?
Panels or images?
Could you supplement your question with more detailed explanations and with explanatory pictures (and/or screenshots).

Comment: I have added a supplement to my original post in an attempt to explain what I mean. Thank you so much for all the help you have given me so far!

Comment: I read the explanations of your question and supplemented my answer with an explanation to them.

Comment: You are incredible! This works exactly like I wanted it too!! Is there any way that I can give you rep or something?

Comment: I don't know much about such aspects of this forum.
You can give a positive review to my answer (up arrow), but in my opinion, you do not have enough reputation for this.
Perhaps there are some other possibilities that I am not aware of.